# How can I find the root of this polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

How  can I  find the  root of this  polynomial?

$f(x) =x^5 - 15x^3-10x^2 +60x   -20 $

My attempts :  By fundamental theorem of algebra, every odd degree polynomial has  at least one root.

But here  I don't know  how to find  the root? And how to break this given polynomial

Comment: [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E5+%2B60x+-+15x%5E3++-10x%5E2+-20%3D0) tells us that this polynomial has no nice roots.

Answer (score 1):

Often it is only possible to find the roots by numerical methods.
Sometimes one can guess a root.
But there is no formula for a root of a 5th degree polynomial as Galois theory tells us. 
Are You sure that the polynomial is correctly written? Or must it be $60x^4$?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "break this polynomial", but the usual procedure to try first is to see if there are any rational roots, which look like factors of $20$ divided by factors of $1$.

If that doesn't work, you must resort to numerical methods, because your polynomial is a quintic, and there is no general solution to the quintic.